# Faster way to apply a function over a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have to apply some multiple functions to a column to get the list of bigrams but it is painfully slow using the apply function the way I'm currently using. Do you have a way to boost the speed?

```
def remove_stop_words(text):
    cleantext = text.lower()
    cleantext = ' '.join(re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', cleantext).strip().split())
    filtered_sentence= ''
    for w in word_tokenize(cleantext):
        if w not in stop_words: 
            filtered_sentence =  filtered_sentence + ' ' + w
    return  filtered_sentence.strip()

def lemmatize(text):
    lemma_word = []
    for w in word_tokenize(text.lower()):
        word1 = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos = "n")
        word2 = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word1, pos = "v")
        word3 = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word2, pos = ("a"))
        lemma_word.append(word3)
    return ' '.join(lemma_word)

def get_ngrams(text, n ):
    n_grams = ngrams(word_tokenize(text), n=2)
    return [ ' '.join(grams) for grams in n_grams]


df['bigrams'] = df.headline.apply(lambda x: get_ngrams(lemmatize(remove_stop_words(x)),n=2))
```

Edit: (based on comment)
The data frame df contains 2 columns - 1. headline 2. Sentiment score

headline - It's news headline, basically text on which I've to apply the function to get the bigrams of the headline

Sentiment Score - I've to keep the score as well in the df dataframe hence need to get a column called "bigram" in the same data frame

[Dataframe df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9PZd.png)

Comment: you won't be able to get around the `apply` to apply the functions. so unless you manage to speed up those, you might want to consider `multiprocessing`, to parallelize the process

Comment: Can you share all relevant code and data? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: I've described the data frame and added an image of how it looks, hope it gives you enough idea

Comment: @WhiteWalker Data in the post itself, please, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this was to parallelize the process using the multiprocessing library.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk.data
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import random
from multiprocessing import  Pool


def get_ngrams(text, n=2 ):
    n_grams = ngrams(text.split(), n=n)
    return [ ' '.join(grams) for grams in n_grams]


def bigrams(df):
    df['bigrams'] = df.headline.apply(lambda x: get_ngrams(lemmatize(remove_stop_words(x)),n=2))
    return df

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=20):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

df2 = parallelize_dataframe(df, bigrams)
bigramScore = df2.explode('bigrams')
```

Note: This is useful only when you have a large number of cores available if you just have 2-3 cores available this might not be the best approach as the overhead cost of parallelizing the process is also to be considered.